How to fix chess.js implementation for index.html
Im trying to build multiplayer chess game and implement it in steps.

Display a chessboard in javascript
Use chess.js to get available moves and playable game
Implement multiplayer, host a server, with ability to change some rules of the game to analyze network data
Use node.js and socket.io for multiplayer

I found another project that works but I want to implement this myself.
However I got stuck on implementing chess.js by itself. The repo contains just a .ts file which I don't know what to do with. I tried to add it to my project but did not work.
https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js
I currently have chessboard.js in my index.html like this:


<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chess</title>

    <!-- Import chessboard css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css">

    <!-- Import jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Import chessboard -->
    <script src="js/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Import chess.js -->
    <!-- <script src="chess.js"></script> -->

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Display chess board -->
    <div id="board1" style="width: 400px"></div>

    <!-- Initialize chess board-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>




There are instructions for installations, but you may use a dist from cdnjs  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/chess.js/0.10.3

@ITgoldman thank you I used this for my game and it works really well. Im wondering if you have any idea of how to implement timer in a nice way for black and white? Currently I just have a vanilla javascript delay of 1 second but that is terrible for client-server communication and just speeds up as time goes on. Im looking into things like websocket but not sure what to do

the server should be the authority when it comes to game data and time.
